# WPF Databind data now showing

Tags: xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I am very new to the MVVM style. I have been able to accomplish everything in the past by writing extensive code in the code behind the XAML. However, I am trying to convert everything into MVVM.

Issue:
I am unable to bind a datagrid to my ObservableCollection. When I debug and walk through my code, the ObservableCollection list is being properly set, meaning, i can view the data within the variables and it shows the data i am adding; however, my data grid does not display the data. Upon reading I found that if I used an ObservableCollection, I didn't need an INotifyPropertyChanged; but because that didn't work, i do have one on there now. Sadly, that still isn't populating my datagrid.

Any help you can offer is appreciated.

In the end, I am going to have a list of type Members, and i need the data grid to populate the data about each member. The data comes from the Members class.

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source=PHList}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
             <DataGridTextColumn Header="Member Name" Binding="{Binding Member_Name}"/>
             <DataGridTextColumn Header="Medicaid ID" Binding="{Binding Medicaid_ID}"/>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Priority Health Model:

```
        public PriorityHealthMember(string name, string id)
    {
        Member_Name = name;
        Medicaid_ID = id;
    }


    private string _Member_Name;

    public String Member_Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Member_Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Member_Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Member_Name");
        }
    }


    private string _Medicaid_ID;

    public String Medicaid_ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _Medicaid_ID;
        }
        set
        {
            _Medicaid_ID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Medicaid_ID");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

Onboarding ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<PriorityHealthMember> _PHList;

    public ObservableCollection<PriorityHealthMember> PhList
    {
        get
        {
            return _PHList;
        }
        set
        {
            _PHList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PhList");
        }
    }
    public OnboardingQueueViewModel()
    {
        PhList = GetOnboardingQueueList();
    }


    private ObservableCollection<PriorityHealthMember> GetOnboardingQueueList()
    {
        ObservableCollection<PriorityHealthMember> list = new ObservableCollection<PriorityHealthMember>();

        list.Add(new PriorityHealthMember("Andrews, Nicholas", "M123456"));//Testing for now. Will add the Business Logic after binding works. 

        return list;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: I found my issue. In my xaml i had "PHList" however, my property was "PhList"

Comment: Always check the debug output for binding errors

Comment: Erno de Weerd! Thank you so much. I have watched hundreds of youtube videos on binding and never came across one that told me that i could see binding error in the debug output!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. In my xaml i had "PHList" however, my property was "PhList"